# Retrieve a full sized image from a picasa link

Tags: javascript, picasa, google-picker, google-photos

for a website I work with several social network APIs to retrieve picture. Currently my problem is with **Google Photo**.

I follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld) to open a google picker with the user picture, but when I click on a picture (inside the Picker), the only link that I have is somethink like https://picasaweb.google.com/userID/albumID#pictureID .

If anyone already face this problem or have a solution...I'm on!

Comment: You may want to try adding **/s value** next to the filename in your URL as suggested in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/u-yNTVkbvYE).

Comment: Thank you, I really could not get this solution, but it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Teyam, I am able to retrieve full sized picture, here is how I do:
1- I retrieve the picture from my album with the google picker (to implement a Google Picker, see [this Google Picker example](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld))
2- In the function pickerCallback instead of returning the docs[0].url to the user, I return the docs[0].thumbnails[0].url
3- I replace the /s32-c/ in the previous url with /s0/ for full sized picture.

Here is my custom getPickerCallback:

```js
function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = '';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        console.log(data);
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var thumbnails = doc[google.picker.Document.THUMBNAILS];
        var url = thumbnails[0].url;
        //now replace the /s32-c/ with /s0/ for full size image
        url = url.replace("/s32-c/","/s0/")
    }
    var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}
```

And if you want to resize the picture, you can do it in the url, for instance if you want 1200xsmth pic, you can set /s1200/ in the url.